# How to get the number of selected indexpath.row of collectionviewcell as slideshare

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to get number of selected cell on a collectionview as slide share app below **"10/53"**

I tired many ways all wrong e.g:
"(print[indexpath.row])" or print"cell[indexpath.row].count"

[image]

```
     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell


    // Configure the cell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
     cell.txxt.text = "Biz memorabilia: 1st day in business, a cold & cloudy day in 1955, @McDonalds did $366.12 in revenue on 2 registers.Biz memorabilia: 1st day in business, a cold & cloudy day in 1955, @McDonalds did $366.12 in revenue on 2 registers."

    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell.txxt.text = "SmartHalo: Turn any bike into a smart bike http://www.producthunt.com/tech/smarthalo  via @gozmike on @producthunt"

    }
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        cell.txxt.text = "Traditionally, policymakers & nonprofits try to improve financial health by measuring & teaching financial literacy"

    }

    //slideNumber is uilabel in the collectionViewCell
    cell.slideNumber.text = "(print[indexpath.row])"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please clear "number of selected cell". And post the code you tried.

Comment: I posted already cell.slideNumber.text = "(print[indexpath.row])"

Comment: if you can notice in the image there is a 10 of 53 I want to do the same

Comment: It means you want to get index of the visible cell. 10/53: cell 10 is visible. Right?

Comment: yes sir this exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using visibleCells to get the current visible, for **10 of 53**:

```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {

        for cell in collectionView.visibleCells() as [CollectionViewCell] {
            var indexPath : NSIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell as CollectionViewCell)!
            // do something
            // display 10 of 53 here        
        }
    }
```

for 10/53 in the cell

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell


    // Configure the cell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
     cell.txxt.text = "Biz memorabilia: 1st day in business, a cold & cloudy day in 1955, @McDonalds did $366.12 in revenue on 2 registers.Biz memorabilia: 1st day in business, a cold & cloudy day in 1955, @McDonalds did $366.12 in revenue on 2 registers."

    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell.txxt.text = "SmartHalo: Turn any bike into a smart bike http://www.producthunt.com/tech/smarthalo  via @gozmike on @producthunt"

    }
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        cell.txxt.text = "Traditionally, policymakers & nonprofits try to improve financial health by measuring & teaching financial literacy"

    }

    //slideNumber is uilabel in the collectionViewCell
    cell.slideNumber.text =  NSString(format: "%d/%d", indexPath.row, totalCell) // totalCell is num of cells you have

    return cell
}
```

Comment: so I've to write it below cellForItemAtIndexPath Right? and should I use  cell.slideNumber.text = print"cell[indexpath.row]"

Comment: it did works after I added  var totalCell = indexPath.row  then first cell was called 0/0 ,sec 1/1 , third 2/2 what is wrong

Comment: fixed it   var totalCell = indexPath.length not row thanks very much

Comment: You have to calculate totalCell. It's the value return from numOfCellInSection. You already have it.